# JavaScript - Hide Options in drop down menu when option is selected

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I have a form on website, made through WordPress, using BeTheme and Contact Form 7. One dropdown list has two options: "Vormittag' Session", and "Abend Session", the other has 5 options: "Premium", "PK1", "PK2", "PK3", "Famille". I would like it so "PK1", "PK2" and "PK3" disappear if "Abend Session" is selected.

Here is the HTML for the two forms:

```
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap menu-772">
 <select name="menu-772" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-select wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
      <option value="Vormittag Session">Vormittag Session</option>
      <option value="Abend Session">Abend Session</option>
 </select>
```

```
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap menu-634">
     <select name="menu-634" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-select wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
        <option value="Premium">Premium</option><option value="PK1">PK1</option>
         <option value="PK2">PK2</option>
         <option value="PK3">PK3</option>
         <option value="Familie">Familie</option>
     </select>
 </span>
```

And here is the JS Code I tried:

```
function hideValues(){
    var x = document.getElementsByName("menu-772");
    var y = document.getElementsByName("menu-634");
         if(x.value="Abend Session")
        {
            y.remove(2);
            y.remove(3);
            y.remove(4);       
         }
}
```

In the above JS code, the idea was to call the two lists x and y, and if the value in x was "Abend Session" then remove positions 2,3 and 4 in y. Am I on the right track or am I way off?

Comment: x.value = "Abend Session" is assigning, not comparing.

Comment: Also in what context are you using the hideValues() function?  This should be used on a 'change' event listener for the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Try `x[0].value=="Abend Session"`. and call  `hideValues()` on select change

`document.getElementsByName` returns a nodelist collection with a given name in the  HTML document.So for selecting the first item use `x[0]`.

Or you can use `element = document.querySelector(selectors);` This will return the first Element within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors.

Also the index will change if you remove one option.so for removing `PK1,PK2,PK3`. you can simply use  `y[0].remove(1);` three times or remove the option with last index first

```js
function hideValues(){
    var x = document.getElementsByName("menu-772");
    var y = document.getElementsByName("menu-634");
 
    if(x[0].value=="Abend Session"){
 
           y[0].remove(3); 
           y[0].remove(2);
           y[0].remove(1);
            
        
    }
      
 
}
```

```html
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap menu-772">
 <select name="menu-772" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-select wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" onchange="hideValues()">
      <option value="Vormittag Session">Vormittag Session</option>
      <option value="Abend Session">Abend Session</option>
 </select>
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap menu-634">
     <select name="menu-634" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-select wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
        <option value="Premium">Premium</option><option value="PK1">PK1</option>
         <option value="PK2">PK2</option>
         <option value="PK3">PK3</option>
         <option value="Familie">Familie</option>
     </select>
 </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, try this. Now it doesn't matter where in the select your PK values are.

```
        function hideValues()
        {
            var Abend = ["PK1", "PK2", "PK3"];
            var x = document.getElementsByName("menu-772");
            var src = document.getElementsByName("menu-634")[0]

            if (x[0].value == "Abend Session")
            {
                for (var count = src.options.length - 1; count >= 0; count--)
                {
                    if (Abend.indexOf(src.options[count].value) != -1)
                    {
                        src.remove(count, null);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```